# Laravel Not Writing Session To Memcached

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, caching, memcached

I have 2 Memcached Servers e.g serv1 and serv2 
Both Work Fine

But when i use it with Laravel Cache,

It works fine when i use serv1.

But when i change the server to serv2. It does not write the Session

I use 1 server at a time. I change the servers IPs.

serv2 works fine when i store data manually and retrieve it, it only gives me issue when i am using it with Laravel.

Both Servers have Memcached Service Installed.

Laravel's code cannot be wrong as it works on serv1.

I cant seem to figure out the problem, been a week since this issue.

Laravel version is 5.6. 
OS is CentOs
THis is my Laravel's Cache.php

the servers are in my env file

```
'memcached' => [

        'driver' => 'memcached',
        'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
        'sasl' => [
            env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
            env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
        ],
        'options' => [
            // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
        ],
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                'weight' => 100,
            ],
```

I have used serv2 to store sessions from vanilla PHP and it is working fine there.

Laravel is storing Values to Cache using Cache:put but not using Session to serv2

Comment: Does serv2 not work only for storing the session? Does it work when set as a Laravel cache?

Comment: it is not working with Laravel Only, even for storing Cache. 
I am using serv2 in Vanilla PHP to store session using htaccess and it is working fine there.

Comment: How are you using it in vanilla PHP ? Can you share Laravel config vs how you use it normally using normal code?

Comment: 'memcached' => [

            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],

Comment: i have set the servers using env. i change it from there

i see that laravel stores the key
but the key has no value when i read from it

Comment: I Tested it again.
Laravel is storing Values to Cache using Cache:put

but not using Session to serv2